# SSH breaks after sending traffic through it using a socks5 proxy (Write failed: Broken pipe)

Tags: firefox, ssh, proxy

I run the following command at home on my local Linux machine:

```
ssh -D 10.0.0.1:443 -C user@internet-server -p 21
```

This opens a listening socket on port 443. Then on another computer I connect to 10.0.0.1:443 socks5 in Firefox. Opening a website now causes the local ssh connection to close with the error `Write failed: Broken pipe`.

The website content itself got loaded but mostly only 50% of it.

I already tried the Timeout directives and ran `top` on the remote server to have some traffic. But this both didn't work because it is pretty much not a timeout. Rather an error when sending traffic through the proxy.

Is this a bug or does a firewall cause this?

Comment: This is no well-known behavior that I'm aware of. Perhaps there is some kind of watchdog software running on the remote SSH server.